# Erro em foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Boa noite galera. Tenho um projeto para uma escola que faz cadastro de dados do aluno e de suas ocorrências. indo direto ao meu problema: O que acontece é que tenho uma página onde mostrar as novas ocorrências que foram geradas no sistema por uma Partial que criei pra mostrar esse tipo de dado. Essa Partial eu to chamando ela na view Index do controller Home, que inclusive nele fiz uma action result pra buscar na tabela ocorrências todas as ocorrências que tem no sistema e mostrar nessa Partial.  A nível de conhecimento, esse controller Home, não tem nada, somente renderiza uma view com as opções que cada usuário pode acessar dependendo do seu perfil. Mas o que está me acontecendo é, em um determinado perfil, eu quero que ao logar, além de mostrar as opções dele mostre essa Partial com as ocorrências, só que logo após que o usuário loga era pra ser mostrado a view Index e junto dela a Partial que criei, só que me retorna um erro dentro do foreach falando que não tem referência ao objeto, mas se eu tento renderizar a partial sozinha, normalmente via link ou via URL direta, ela funciona e mostra os dados numa boa... Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

## Controller(Aqui vou mostrar somente a ActionResult pra agilizar)

```
    private EntidadesContext db;
    public HomeController(EntidadesContext contexto)
    {
        this.db = contexto;
    }
    public ActionResult PartialOcorrencias(long? id, int? pagina)
    {
        List<Ocorrencia> resultado = db.Ocorrencias.Include(o => o.Aluno).ToList();

        int paginaTamanho = 25;
        int paginaNumero = (pagina ?? 1);
        var ocorrencias = resultado;

        return PartialView("PartialOcorrencias", ocorrencias.ToPagedList(paginaNumero, paginaTamanho));
    }
```

## View(Home/Index)

```
       @using CEF01.Filters

        @{
             ViewBag.Title = "Olá";
                Verify.setVerify(Session[".PermissionCookie"].ToString());
         }

       <div class="container">
              <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2 class="text-center">Bem Vindo ao <i>Sistema de Gestão de Alunos - SGA</i></h2>
    <br />

    <article>
       <h3> Olá, @User.Identity.Name</h3>
    </article>

    @if (Verify.isProfessor())
    {
        @Html.Partial("_PartialProfessor")
    }
    else if (Verify.isCoordenador())
    {
        @Html.Partial("_PartialCoordenador")
        @Html.Partial("PartialOcorrencias")
    }
    else if (Verify.isAdmin())
    {
        @Html.Partial("_PartialProfessor")
        @Html.Partial("_PartialCoordenador")
        @Html.Partial("_PartialAdministrador")          
    }       

    <h3>Centro de Ensino Fundamental 01 - Riacho Fundo II</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

## Partial(PartialOcorrencias, e é nesse foreah que ele alega o erro)

```
@*@model IEnumerable<CEF01.Models.Ocorrencia>*@
@model PagedList.IPagedList<CEF01.Models.Ocorrencia>
 @using PagedList.Mvc;
  <link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Aluno.Nome)*@
        Nome do Aluno
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Aluno.Nome)
            @Html.ActionLink("Resolver", "Edita", new { id = item.Id })                
        </td>
    </tr>        
}
</table>
 Pagina @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) de @Model.PageCount
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model, pagina => Url.Action("PartialOcorrencias", new { pagina, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu realmente entendi, você simplesmente deseja renderizar uma *Partial* que é do tipo `PagedList.IPagedList<CEF01.Models.Ocorrencia>` na *View* Index.

Então, quando você renderiza sua *Partial* (no caso na sua View Index), você precisa passar isso como parâmetro. Esse parâmetro será o *Model* que o *foreach* da sua *Partial* vai iterar, não pode estar nulo, senão você vai receber uma [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Na sua View Index teríamos por exemplo:

```
//ModelDaIndex.ListaDeOcorrencias ou o parâmetro que você for passar para a Partial
//não pode estar nulo, pois a Partial depende dele para ser populada
@Html.Partial("_PartialOcorrencias", ModelDaIndex.ListaDeOcorrencias)
```

---

**Edição:**

Conforme foi solicitado uma explicação melhor, segue um exemplo de como Rendererizar uma Partial View na Index:

Criando uma classe Ocorrencia

```
public class Ocorrencia
{
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Criando o model da index com uma lista de ocorrências

```
public class ModelDaIndex
{
    public ModelDaIndex()
    {
        ListaDeOcorrencias = PreencherListaDeOcorrencias();
    }

    //Propriedade com a lista de ocorrências
    public List<Ocorrencia> ListaDeOcorrencias { get; set; }

    //Método que apenas retorna uma lista de ocorrências
    public List<Ocorrencia> PreencherListaDeOcorrencias()
    {
        List<Ocorrencia> listaDeOcorrencias = new List<Ocorrencia>();
        listaDeOcorrencias.Add(new Ocorrencia()
        {
            Descricao = "Ocorrência 1"
        });
        listaDeOcorrencias.Add(new Ocorrencia()
        {
            Descricao = "Ocorrência 2"
        });
        return listaDeOcorrencias;
    }
}
```

Criando uma Partial View para iterar sobre as ocorrências e listá-las na view Index

```
@model Mvc4Application.Models.ModelDaIndex

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_PartialOcorrencias";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Minha _PartialOcorrencias</h2>

@if (Model.ListaDeOcorrencias != null)
{     
    <table>            
        <tr>
            <th>
                Descrição
            </th>            
        </tr>
        @foreach (var ocorrencia in Model.ListaDeOcorrencias)
        {
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    @ocorrencia.Descricao
                </td>                                
            </tr> 
        }
    </table>
}
```

Criando a view Index com o helper para renderizar a Partial View

```
@model Mvc4Application.Models.ModelDaIndex
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

Código e lógica da sua View Index....

Renderizando a Partial View:
<div>
    @Html.Partial("_PartialOcorrencias", Model)
</div>
```

Note que você precisa passar um parâmetro (que no caso será o Model utilizado na Partial) para a sua Partial View, caso contrário ocorrerá um erro conforme coloquei no início da resposta.

[image: Adicionando parâmetro para usar na Partial]

Se ainda não ficou claro, tem um [link aqui](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/aravindbenator/mvc-3-razor-and-partial-view/) explicando também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ainda não entendi muito bem... Poderia me explicar de novo ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago editei a resposta, acredito que você vai conseguir entender.

Comment: agora consegui entender sim. Mas, tenho uma dúvida: Porque a necessidade de se criar um model somente pra isso ? Num posso fazer essa operação de mostrar todos os dados do banco de uma tabela em um Controller ou uma View diferente ? Porque eu já fiz uma partial pra mostrar na view de detalhes(Alunos) além dos dados do aluno suas ocorrencias(então criei uma partial pra ser renderizada nessa view de detalhes). Então o que acontece é que: renderizei uma partial com as ocorrências do aluno juntamente com seus dados, ou seja, dados diferentes, mas renderizados juntos. Queria fazer isso tmb.

Comment: Resolvi aqui cara ! Valeu ae pela ajuda !